# Generic GDI+ Exception Followed by OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: vb.net, gdi+, out-of-memory, activereports

I'm working on a VB.Net WinForms app. This app shows rows of production lines that the user will go down row by row and print a package of ActiveReports documents. This package can contain up to 9 reports. The package is selected and told to print, it then gets sent directly to the default printer of the machine using ActiveReports' mechanism:

```
rpt.Document.Print(False, False, True)
```

These reports also use images pulled in from the file system. When they run through the rows quickly, they sometimes encounter:

```
A generic error ocurred in GDI+
```

Then followed by:

```
Exception of type "System.OutOfMemoryException" was thrown.
```

This causes some documents to not print and they have to go back and figure out which ones didn't print. I know the machine is not out of memory, so my assumption is that the printer memory is filling up or reports are trying to use the same image when printing and causing an issue there.

If it is the printer memory filling up, is there any way to slow down the adding of documents to the print queue, or at least pausing to wait for space? I'm kind of at a loss and would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: I did send them a support email as well and am still waiting to hear back. I'm going to try to sleep the thread in between packages to see if maybe it will wait for some printer memory to clear up. I was also thinking saving the reports as a PDF then sending them to the printer. Can I use the Adobe SDK to send PDFs directly to the printer from a file?

Comment: Can you please provide a callstack for the "A generic error occurred in GDI+" error? This would help a great deal in isolating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to just use the caching capability built into ActiveReports. That seemed to alleviate some of the problems with the printer. I also added some slowing down of the thread in order to make sure the memory clears out before adding more documents to the print queue. Thanks.